# How do I pass a numeric value to a mysql script

Tags: mysql

How do I pass a parameter (numeric) from the command line to MySQL query file?

```
mysql --host=<hostname> --user=<username> -p --port=#### < Query.sql > Output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to transform your `Query.sql` file, then pass it to `mysql`. The `mysql` program itself doesn't have any parameter substitution capability.

For example, in linux or freebsd.

```
cat 'SELECT @numericParameter := 42;' >/tmp/param$$
cat /tmp/param$$ Query.sql | mysql  --host=<hostname> --user=<username> -p --port=#### > Output.csv
rm /tmp/param$$
```

The first line of this shell script writes one line of SQL, setting a parameter, into a temp file.

The second line sticks that one line at the beginning of your SQL file and pipes the result to the `mysql` client program.

The third line deletes the temp file.

This leaves your SQL file unmodified when it's done. That's probably what you want.